# Are photons emergent or fundamental?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

Maxwell’s equations seem to imply that light is an emergent phenomenon that emerges through fluctuations in the EM field.

On the other hand according to the standard model, photons are fundamental particles and are conveyors of the electromagnetic force.

Since photons are packages of light, it seems that there is a contradiction here. How can they be fundamental from one perspective, but emergent from another?

I expect the answer to be something like “photons and light are not exactly the same”. If this really is the case, what exactly is the relation between them?

People've pointed out that what I mean by emergent and fundamental isn't clear. By fundamental I mean that something isn't, at least in our current knowledge, an effect or aspect of anything else. That it is akin to a mathametical axiom. For example I woulld consider spacetime to be fundamental whereas gravity to be emergent for it emerges from the properties of this fundamental thing. At least according to my current understanding there is no underlying object that causes spacetime, or the properties that it has.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "light is an emergent phenomenon that emerges through fluctuations in the EM field".  Is magnetic induction such as it is used in a transformer also emergent?

Comment: Electromagnetic waves are solutions of Maxwell equations - it is not clear what *emergent* means here.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you can give other examples for "emergent" and "fundamental" to help us better understand your question?

Comment: @garyp Meaning that its existence and properties follows from the properties of the electromagnetic field. Just using the facts layed out in the Maxwell’s equations you can conclude that disturbances in the electromagnetic field will propogate with the speed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon\mu}}$ whic is c. Also the properties such as interferance, diffraction, reflection etc. are all explainable.

Comment: Physics isn't axiomatic and deductive (like some maths attempts to be), but empirical and inductive. We don't postulate the existence of "things" and deduce from those other "things". For instance, if you had an empty universe (no mass or energy or quantum fluctuations), would you still have your fundamental space-time? If you claim yes, then that claim is probably not scientific, as it cannot be tested and has no predictive power.

Comment: Try again with a new question of a better formulation. You got some kind of answer anyway. +1